# Number overflowing from list item pseudo element in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple unordered list of links and am using psuedo elements to create numbers for the list. For some reason in IE11 I cannot get the number to center vertically in it's circle background.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>Link 2</a>
  </li>  
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>Link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
.list-item {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  color: $c-white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;

  a {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3.8rem;

    &:before {
      color: $c-white;
      content: counter(step-counter);
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      height: 2.4rem;
      width: 2.4rem;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-right: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 2.6rem;
      top: -.5rem;
      background-color:teal;
    }
  }
}
```

The numbers in IE11:

[image]

The numbers in all other browsers:

[image]

Comment: Any way you could reproduce this in a js.fiddle or supply more of your scss code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle out of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/7mwgzeba/

That's a well known bug (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/776744). Setting a *rem* value in the `line-height` property results always being calculated to "1px".
Microsoft claims that they resolved the bug in IE11 and edge (so it's not fixed in any version of IE prior to 11 at all), but apparently it's still there.
Using *em* instead of *rem* seems to work at least in IE11.

---

Since it only affects pseudo-elements, you could do a work-around like: https://jsfiddle.net/7mwgzeba/1/

Every list-item, gets an empty span

```
<li class="list-item">
    <a><span></span>Link 1</a>
</li>
```

... and the styling in the **SCSS** is just moved to it:

```
/* ... */
a {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3.8rem;

    span {
        color: $c-white;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        height: 2.4rem;
        width: 2.4rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-right: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 2.6rem;
        top: -.5rem;
        background-color:teal;

        &:before {
            content: counter(step-counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!